# Do Chipettes speak with a specific dialect in the Alvin and the Chipmunks movies?

Tags: dialogue, alvin-and-the-chipmunks

In the Czech dubbing of the *Alvin and the Chipmunks* films, the Chipettes speak the Slovak language instead of the Czech language, as other characters in the movie do (they are very similar, speakers of both languages understand each other). This is due to the fact that Czech men love the voice of Slovak women.

Does the movie in the original language also have the Chippetes using a specific accent to make them more likable, or was this only done in the Czech version?

Comment: Hello! While I think I understand the nature of your question, it would benefit if there was more clarification, as the body of the Q actually doesn't have a question in it. Thank you.

Comment: What is "**the** Chipmunks movie"?  The Chipettes have appeared in at least half a dozen movies.

Comment: Ray Buuterworth - I mean  Alvin and the Chipmunks: The Squeakquel and sequels.

Comment: Aren't they from dow unda mate (australia)?